# Translate store view name based on current store magento

Tags: magento2, multilingual

I have a multi-language store in magento 2, and I want to translate the name of the store views depending on which language I currently am on.
For example if I am on en in the language dropdown I want to show: English/ French.
But if I am on fr in the language dropdown I want to show: Anglais/ Francais.
Is this think possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (for those who want this), you can edit the name of the storeview in the csv file each language indivually, so when you're on the english store it will appear English/French but when you are on the french store it will appear Anglais/Francais